# Disable button interaction when input is blank

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to make something similar to the spotify login screen. When either the username or password field is blank, the login button is disabled and cannot be pressed. I am not sure how to consistently check if the fields are blank, so I attempted to use the textFieldDidEndEditing, though it is not currently working. This is what I have so far. Is there a more efficient way to fix this?

```
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        if (usernameField.text! == "" || passwordField.text! == "") {
            loginButton.userInteractionEnabled = false
            loginButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.redColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            print("field empty")
        }
    }
```

Also, here are screenshots for reference on what the end goal is.

[image: No input]
[image: Input]

*(ps, sorry for the size of photo, I don't know how to make it smaller)*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem with Animals help. This problem can be solved very easily by simply creating a new IBAction with the password field and adding the following code:

```
    @IBAction func passwordEditing(sender: AnyObject) {
    if self.usernameField.text! != "" && self.passwordField.text! != ""{
        loginButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.redColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        loginButton.userInteractionEnabled = true
        print("both fields ok!")
    } else {
        loginButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can listen to the textfields **`editingChanged`** event instead of the didEndEditing

```
@IBAction func editingChanged(sender: AnyObject) {
    if usernameField.text != "" && passwordField.text != "" {
        loginButton.enabled = true
    } else {
        loginButton.enabled = false
    }
}
```

Then just hook up both textFields `editingChanged` through code or interface builder.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! I made an answer with working code.

Answer (score 0):

you could do it like this:

disable your loginbutton by default since the textfields are empty when the login screen appears...

and implement the following textfield's delegate method:

Swift

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if textField == usernameField {
      loginButton.enabled = ((textField.text! as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string).characters.count > 0 && passwordField.text?.characters.count > 0)
    } else if textField == passwordField {
      loginButton.enabled = ((textField.text! as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string).characters.count > 0 && usernameField.text?.characters.count > 0)
    }

    return true
  }
```

ObjC

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
  if (textField == self.usernameField) {
    self.loginButton.enabled = ([textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string].length > 0 && self.passwordField.text.length > 0);
  } else if (textField == self.passwordField) {
    self.loginButton.enabled = ([textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string].length > 0 && self.usernameField.text.length > 0);
  }

  return YES;
}
```